# Installation issue on IBM Websphere

Tags: websphere, devops

We have a module that needs to be installed on 5 different servers. The installation is OK on 4 of them, but always fails on the fifth one.

Here is an anonymized log extract :

> [8/8/18 13:55:04:145 CEST] 0000002c ActivationSpe E   J2CA0138E: The Message Endpoint activation failed for ActivationSpec mq/MQ_AS_ (com.ibm.mq.connector.inbou
>   nd.ActivationSpecImpl) and MDB application ## due to the following exception: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA0001: An exception occurred in the JMS layer. See the linked exception for
>   details., error code: MQJCA0001 A call to WebSphere MQ classes for JMS caused an exception to be thrown. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
>   [8/8/18 13:55:04:233 CEST] 0000002c ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting,

Fact : this activation spec connects to another environment. Therefore our guess is that the connexion between the two cannot be established.

Questions are :

- Can this error block an installation ? I can't see why an endpoint critically matters to the module installation.
- Since the installation is OK on the other servers, could maybe the configuration is different between the servers. Does anyone know of a property that could alter the error management on this server ? Like block the installation in case of any error ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please share the complete exception trace for the connection issue (any AMQ* error codes) from the JVM logs? Also are there any exceptions/errors logged at the Queue manager side?

Comment: I don't have this information, we aren't the server owner and I only have a limited access to logs. Therefore, I was asking for advices and best practices when dealing with this issue, in order to suggest the best way to debug this to the owning team :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can easily validate the configurations by comparing the resources.xml files (at *Dmgr_Profile > Config > Cells > Cell_name > Nodes > Node_name > Servers > Server_Name* directory) of the failing JVM with the working one.

Search for the line starting with "***j2cActivationSpec***" tag and containing the name of your activation spec in the resources.xml file and compare all the resource properties of the activationSpec to identify the difference.

If you could get more logs, I can provide better suggestions, as mentioned in my comments above.

If nothing works, for the mean time you can disable the activation spec startup during server start, by setting a custom property "***WAS_EndpointInitialState***", with value "***INACTIVE***" for the activation spec, till the actual issue is identified. More details [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rmj_wmq_mp_custproperties.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about that custom property, it might come in handy :) For now, we've provided them a telnet tutorial in order to test each of there Queue Managers, we are waiting their answer. If it isn't a connectivity issue, we'll give a try at your resources.xml clue, I'll keep you informed